# Disk partition when no any window is installed

Tags: windows, boot-partition

I don't have any windows in my PC, actually I have uninstall windows 7 the other day.

Now I tried to install windows 10 and when it was ask to choose disk, by mistake I was just deleted the system disk (c) and now it is showing as unallocated space.

Therefore I can't choose next for installation of windows 10. 
and i'm unable to create new partition from 'Unallocated Space'

Comment: Which screen are you talking about ? Also, if you have PE loaded pressing `Shift + F10` would start command prompt and then you can run diskpart

Comment: Did you select the unallocated drive?, this should cause the next button to become active.

Answer (score 2):

Click the "Unallocated Space"

and you should see a button called "new"

Select that.

This will create a new partition.

After creating that you should be able to choose it and hit next to continue with the installation.

Comment: Windows 7 could install on an unallocated partition, done it a thousand times, selected it and hit next, did something change in W10 install routine? Maybe they did not select it.

Comment: it depends i find, sometimes i can install no problem, then others i get awful hassle with partition issue, sometimes with windows 10 if the is already a primary partition detected it will not allow you to install on a secondary partition which is annoying and can cause issues with dual booting. I've never looked into it much as it only upsets what im doing for 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Yeah, but we are talking unallocated, which means no partitions or formatting, a raw drive. I think they forgot to select it, the next button is always grayed out until you select (highlight) a drive or partition.